# VBScript, Delete Exact String Only

Tags: vbscript

Hi I have the following VBscript to remove printers, however when I run it, it is also deleting just Canon IR70.

```
Dim aPrinterModels(2)
aPrinterModels(0)="Canon IR70 (Cpoy 1)"
aPrinterModels(1)="Canon IR70 (Cpoy 2)"
aPrinterModels(2)="Canon IR70 (Cpoy 3)"

for each printer in aPrinterModels
    RemovePrinterAndPort(printer)
next

Sub RemovePrinterAndPort(strModelMask)
    on error resume next
    msiMessageTypeError = &H01000000 
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
    'objWMIService.Security_.Privileges.AddAsString "SeLoadDriverPrivilege", True
    Set colInstalledPrinters =  objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Printer where name like'" & strModelMask & "%'") 
    if colInstalledPrinters.count<>0 then   
        For each objPrinter in colInstalledPrinters
            Set colInstalledPorts =  objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort where name like '" & objPrinter.PortName & "'")
            objPrinter.Delete_
            For Each objPort in colInstalledPorts 
                objPort.Delete_
            Next
        Next
    end if
    Set colInstalledPrinters = Nothing
    Set colInstalledPorts = nothing 
    Set objWMIService = Nothing
End Sub
```

How can I get it to only delete the exact string in aPrinterModels??

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to match the exact string then why not use `=` in lieu of `like`?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot try `wmi` query with your scenario and `like` comparison but I'd use `=` comparison as follows:

```
Set colInstalledPrinters = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
  "Select * from Win32_Printer where name = '" & strModelMask & "'")
```

The code snippet with `objPort.Delete` execute only on the assumption that *ports* for copied printer instances *differ* from original printer port. 
In more presumable case of the same *port*  for all printer instances (original and copies): modify code snippet with `objPort.Delete` to be performed conditionally or suppress it at all and remove unused ports as an independent task:

```
for each printer in aPrinterModels
    RemovePrinter(printer)
next
RemoveUnusedPorts

Sub RemovePrinter(strModelMask)
    'on error resume next
    msiMessageTypeError = &H01000000 
    Set objWMIService = GetObject( _
      "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colInstalledPrinters = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
    "Select * from Win32_Printer where name = '" & strModelMask & "'") 
if colInstalledPrinters.count<>0 then
    For each objPrinter in colInstalledPrinters
        ' wscript.Echo "Printer to Delete " & objPrinter.Name
        objPrinter.Delete_
    Next
end if
Set colInstalledPrinters = Nothing
Set objWMIService = Nothing
End Sub

Sub RemoveUnusedPorts
   ' code snippet to remove unused ports here
End Sub
```

Comment: I have a number of different printer names (36) I want to do this with, so is there a way I can do the = to get the exact string name only?